# Proving a property of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,\oplus,\odot)$ be a vector space. Let $u\in V$ and let $v$ be the additive inverse of $u$. Prove that if $w\in V$ is a vector such that $u\oplus w= w\oplus u = 0_{V}$, then $w=v$.

Here I have no idea where to start. I guess I shall gather all the information I have right now:

$v$ is the additive inverse of $u$ so $u\oplus v = v\oplus u = 0_{V}$. Now I just don't see any way of logically concluding that $w=v$. I can see it is true but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $v = v\oplus (u\oplus w) =(v \oplus u) \oplus w=  w.$

*Note:* $(V , \oplus)$ is an additive group. So (additive) inverse of every element of $V$ is unique. That's what you need to prove, nothing more.